# MethodInfo.CreateDelegate throws exception

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, delegates

I am having problems with the `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` on a win8.1 phone project, it just seems to return an error even though I can manually create a delegate instance.

```
Private thisworksFine As New returnDel(AddressOf WorkWith_Return)
```

The error I get returned is

> methodIf.CreateDelegate(GetType(returnDel2))   {System.ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature or security transparency is not compatible with that of the delegate type.     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CreateDelegateInternal(Type delegateType, Object firstArgument, DelegateBindingFlags bindingFlags, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)     at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CreateDelegate(Type delegateType)} System.ArgumentException

This is the code

```
Private Delegate Sub returnDel(intErrorId As Integer, strErrorMsg As String)

Private Sub WorkWith_Return(intErrorId As Integer, strErrorMsg As String)

End Sub

Sub sDeligateTesting()
    Dim methodInfos As MethodInfo() = GetType(MyClass).GetRuntimeMethods()

    For Each methodIf As MethodInfo In methodInfos
        If methodIf.Name = "WorkWith_Return" Then
            Dim ThisDoesNotWork = methodIf.CreateDelegate(GetType(returnDel)) <--Errror here
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me by pointing out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could put in the error you get.

Answer (score 1):

Just solved it this morning so I thought I would share the fix in case anyone else is having the same problem. I just had to add `me` and the delegate matches the one created with this line:

```
Private thisworksFine As New returnDel(AddressOf WorkWith_Return)
```

Working code:

```
Dim ThisDoesNotWork = methodIf.CreateDelegate(GetType(returnDel),me)
```